# Send browser JavaScript errors to Stackdriver Error Reporting

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, error-reporting, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I have a client-side JavaScript application and I would like to report errors and exceptions to Stackdriver Error Reporting.

Answer (score 9):

Stackdriver Error Reporting can process errors coming from client-side JavaScript.

You need a [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) project.
Then [enable the Stackdriver Error Reporting API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com) and [get an API key](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862).

Reporting client-side error is done by calling the [report API endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report) with an API key.

---

You can use this JavaScript module to normalize the exception stack traces, and send them to Stackdriver in the expected format: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-errors-js

Example:

```
<!-- Warning: This is an experimental library, do not use it on production environments -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stackdriver-errors-js@0.7.0/dist/stackdriver-errors-concat.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var errorHandler = new StackdriverErrorReporter();
  errorHandler.start({
    key: '<my-api-key>',
    projectId: '<my-project-id>'
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't the API key specifically designed for trusted environments only? I don't think you're supposed to expose the api key on a front end application.